# Normal subgroups of $S_n$ and even permutations

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

I'm refreshing some basic group theory so excuse in advance the basic questions. In $S_3$ one can isolate the alternating group $A_3$ by looking at the even permutations. Is it true in general that the alternating group $A_n$ can be isolated as the group of all even permutations of $S_n$?

In addition is the set of all corresponding permutation matrices in $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ also a normal subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$.

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't that how the alternating group is defined?

Comment: Ah yes it is the definition! I was reading something else and skipped over the definition! Thanks. Now so now $A_n$ is always the kernel of a homomorphism, right? So it's a normal subgroup, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it true in general that the alternating group $A_n$ can be isolated as the group of all even permutations of $S_n?$

Yes, as it is one way to define the alternating group $A_n$.

Comment: Thanks Shaun. On a different note also, my understanding is that it's always a normal subgroup because it can be realized as the kernel of a homomorphism, generalizing the $A_3$ and $S_3$ set up. Is that the only normal subgroup of $S_n$?

Comment: *Is that the only normal subgroup of $S_n$?* Apparently so, yes, @16278263789, according to a Google search of "normal subgroups of $S_n$."

Comment: Be careful though. It is the only *proper* normal subgroup, @16278263789.

Comment: $A_n$ is the only proper non-identity normal subgroup of $S_n$, except that $S_4$ has an extra one, isomorphic to the Klein group. (The kernel of the action on the three partitions of shape $[2,2]$ of a set of size $4$.)

Comment: Yes, I forgot that, @verret; thank you.

Comment: Thank you to both of you, pretty cool.